# Rails CanCan Hash of Conditions Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have a simple Ability.rb set up listed below:

```
if user.role? :super_admin
  can :manage, :all
elsif user.role? :registered
  can :review, [Card, Deck], :visible => true
end
```

Where the `alias :review => :index, :list, :show, :to`. Both Card and Deck tables have the visible column with the boolean option. Currently every object in the tables have `:visible => false`. Therefore, I'm expecting that a user with the registered role will not be able to `:review` any of the objects, but this is not the case. Restrictions at the controller level works fine (edit and delete are not accessible), but I can't seem to restrict the viewing of resources using the hash of conditions. Any thoughts?

Edit: I have `authorize_resource` in the two controllers. Using Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.1, and CanCan 1.6.7. I'm using devise 1.4.9 for authentication. MySQL is the database.

Edit:
Well.. I figured out a way to restrict resources based on the conditions. Even though I had authorize_resource in all my controllers  (and it worked for restricting access to the methods), I had to add `authorize!` to the methods that I wanted to restrict the resources to. For example, to restrict the show action for Decks with the condition of `:visible => true`, I had to add `authorize!` as such:

```
def show
  @deck = Deck.find(params[:deck_id]
  authorize! :review, @deck
end
```

To be honest, I am not satisfied with this solution, since I don't see a reason why `authorize_resource` wouldn't work. I would love to see an explanation.

Comment: Having the same issue, did you end up finding a proper solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found a solution. The project was abandoned, and I haven't run into this problem in the future projects I've worked on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you calling

```
load_resource_authorize_resource
```

in your controller just like that, or are you including a model to authorize?

I discovered that I can replicated your issue if I type something like:

```
load_resource_authorize_resource Deck
```

I think the reason the latter doesn't work because you are asking CanCan to authorize "Deck" arbitrarily, as opposed to authorizing a controller action, which is what you really want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can see this topic:
[Cancan condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393834/cancan-condition)

I have the same problem with you, and I solve it by that topic,
I replaced `authorize_resource` by `load_and_authorize_resource`

Answer (score 0):

Hm, restart the server? Your code looks good to me.

Comment: Believe me when I say I must've restarted the server an obscene amount of times :( I wish this was the solution, but it isn't.