# Cancan condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I'm using CanCan in a project to manage different role level on each entity for each project.
I'm doing this:

```
# encoding: utf-8
class Ability
    include CanCan::Ability 
    def initialize(user)
        user ||= User.new            
        if user.is_admin == true
            can :manage, :all
        else 
            can :read, :all
            Project.all.each do |project|
                current_role_name = user.roles.find_by_project_id(project.id).role_name.name
                if current_role_name.eql?'Auteur senior'
                    can :manage, [Project, Introduction, Abstract, Text, Conclusion, Asset, Attachment], :project_id => project.id
                elsif current_role_name.eql?'Auteur junior'
                    can :manage, [Introduction, Abstract, Attachment], :project_id => project.id
                    can :update, Text, :project_id => project.id, :user_level => current_role_name 
                    can :manage, [Asset], :project_id => project.id, :user_level => current_role_name
                elsif current_role_name.eql?'Équipe phylogéniste'
                    can :manage, [Attachment], :project_id => project.id
                    can :manage, [Text, Asset], :project_id => project.id, :user_level => current_role_name
                end
            end    
        end
    end 
end
```

It works when I check the user role_name but after when I want to use condition like this:

```
can :update, Text, :project_id => project.id, :user_level => current_role_name
```

The condition doesn't have any effect. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution :

In concerned controller I replaced authorize_resource by load_and_authorize_resource and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

What I usely do is:

**1- defining roles in my User class and affect them to users.**

```
class User
  # CanCan roles ( see Users::Ability)
  ROLES = %w[auteur_senior auteur_junior]

  def roles=(roles)
    self.roles_mask = (roles & ROLES).map { |r| 2**ROLES.index(r) }.sum
  end

  def roles
    ROLES.reject do |r|
      ((roles_mask || 0) & 2**ROLES.index(r)).zero?
    end
  end

  def is?(role)
    roles.include?(role.to_s)
  end

  # define all bollean set/get methods for roles
  ROLES.each do |r|
    define_method "is_#{r}" do
      self.roles += [r]
      self
    end
    define_method "is_#{r}?" do
      roles.include?(r)
      self
    end
  end
end
```

**2-In the ability I affect the capabilities of each roles**

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    @user = user || User.new  # for guest

    @user.roles.each { |role| send(role) }
  end

  def auteur_junior
    can :manage, [Introduction, Abstract, Attachment], :project_id => project.id
    can :update, Text, :project_id => project.id, :user_level => current_role_name 
    can :manage, [Asset], :project_id => project.id, :user_level => current_role_name
  end

  def auteur_scenior
    can :manage, [Project, Introduction, Abstract, Text, Conclusion, Asset, Attachment], :project_id => project.id
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The `authorize_resource` method calls `authorize!` on the class unless it is passed an instance. Without using `load_resource` or `load_and_authorize_resource`, you're passing nil to the `authorize_resource` before_filter.

[Example from the CanCan documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/ryanb/cancan/CanCan%2FControllerAdditions%2FClassMethods%3Aauthorize_resource):

```
#authorize_resource(*args) ⇒ Object
authorize!(params[:action].to_sym, @article || Article)
```

If you want to load records from the database with your own method (instead of CanCan's `load_resource`) and have more control, then you can create your own method like `load_thing` and call it with `prepend_before_filter :load_thing`. **This will load the record into the instance variable before `authorize_resource` is called, ensuring the instance variable isn't nil and the rules specified in the ability file are checked.**